# Javascript JSON get id from value

Tags: javascript, json

I have been working on a javascript application and I am attempting to get the value of "id" using a different key/value pair. My JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "value": "Hermitage Park",
      "type": "Park",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

My Javascript:

```
function GetID(value) {
    var output = 0
    fetch("http://localhost:8088/data").then(storage => 
        storage.json()).then(items => {
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {              
                if (items[i]["value"] == value) {
                    output = i
                    break
                }
            }             
    })
    return output
}
```

When calling the function, I specified "Hermitage Park" as the value, hoping to get back the value of the "id" property, which is 2.  It seems right to me, but it always returns 0 when it should be 2.  I also tried `items[value]["id"]` and `items[value].id`, but nothing is working so far.

Comment: It should return `null`, not `0`. Please see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/4642212). Next, if `items` is the object you’ve shown us, then `id` is at `items.data[0].id`. See [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212).

Comment: You can use destructuring: `.then({data: items} => { ... })`. You can also break out of the loop once you've found the value.

Comment: `fetch()` is asynchronous. You're returning `output` before it completes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Sorry, I had gotten mixed up (I am not very good at javascript)

Comment: Regardless of the asynch problems others pointed out, you're returning the index of the item, not the item id itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` is an asynchronous method that returns a `Promise`. You're really close! What's missing is that `GetID()` is not returning the promise returned by `fetch`. Since it's not returning the promise there's no way for the caller of the function to wait for the value. The request eventually resolves, but the function has already returned `0` and your code has continued executing.

This can be rewritten as:

```js
function GetID(value) {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8088/data")
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(({ data }) => {
            const item = data.find(item => item.value === value);
            return item.id;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is an Asynchronous function so you need to make GetID function async,
Basically we can't return from async function and assign it into a variable.
You can do following way:

```
async function GetID(value) {
  var output = null;
  let response = await fetch("../myjson.json");
  let result = await response.json();
  let data = result["data"];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i]["value"] === value) {
      output = data[i]["id"];
    }
  }
  return output;
};
GetID("Hermitage Park").then( value => console.log(value));
```

From this function we will get back a Promise and then we can get that value from that Promise. As you can see the last line of the code
https://dev.to/johnpaulada/synchronous-fetch-with-asyncawait

Comment: can't specify a .json file in the "fetch" function; it only works with "http" or "https"

Comment: @S.Ferrell, I was testing the code on my local machine so that's why I put local path. You can specify the http or https path whatever you want